# .net won't clear listboxes if redirecting

Tags: asp.net, redirect, listbox

I have some asp.Net listboxes on a page. After my code has read the contents and constructed a sql string, I redirect to a page to display the results. I'd like to clear the listboxes before I leave the page, to leave it tidy in case the user wants to return and do another search.

I can clear the list boxes like this:

```
    'Clear all selections
    lstDescription.SelectedIndex = -1
    lstManufacturer.SelectedIndex = -1
    lstModelNumber.SelectedIndex = -1
    lstIssuedTo.SelectedIndex = -1
    lstLocation.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Works, great, but if I add this line below:

```
    Response.Redirect("grid.aspx")
```

The boxes don't clear - I can press the back button and they're still selected. Can anyone tell me why asp.net behaves this way? Any suggestions for a workaround would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing browser behavior, not ASP.NET behavior specifically.  The page you are redirecting from and subsequently returning to via the back button is being served by the browser from the cache and so retains its settings.

You need to tell the browser not to do this.  Add this code to the Page_Load and IE and FireFox will stop serving from the cache:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    ...
```

All browsers implement caching differently and that is beyond your control as they all interpret what you send back in the Response according to their rules and idiom.  For example, the snippet above works for IE and FireFox, but not Chrome.

Comment: Great, that's exactly it. Thanks not only for solving my problem but for explaining what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this :

> lstDescription.SelectedItem = Nothing

Let me know if you still face it.

Comment: javalovers, thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, but it's telling me that SelectedItem is read-only. So I guess you can't use it that way. Any other suggestions gladly accepted. Mainly, I'd like some MVP to explain this weird behavior, I just don't get it.